# How to give the Nodejs Child process a name

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm trying to give a child process a name but I don't know how to do it

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
  let cpr = exec('node server.js');
```

I'm using the exec function to run the child process, I'm using WINDOWS

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to give the child process a name, so I can see it in the task manager